# Trying to configure method "first" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

I'll try to create a mock objet to test my application and i've got an error thant i can't fix :

```
    $userOwnLevy = $this->createMock(User::class);

    $userHasContract = $this->createMock(UserHasContract::class);
    $userHasContract->method('getUser')->willReturn($userOwnLevy);

    $firstUserHasContract = $this
        ->getMockBuilder(UserHasContract::class)
        ->getMock()
        ->method('first')
        ->willReturn($userHasContract);

    $contract = $this->createMock(Contract::class);
    $contract->method('getUserHasContract')->willReturnMap([$firstUserHasContract]);

    $levy = $this->createMock(Levy::class);
    $levy->method('getContract')->willReturn($contract);
```

The goal is to mock this object :

```
$levy->getContract()->getUserHasContract()->first()->getUser();
```

I try this :

```
        $firstUserHasContract = $this
        ->getMockBuilder(UserHasContract::class)
        ->setMethods(['first'])
        ->getMock()
        ->method('first')
        ->willReturn($userHasContract);
```

But i got this error

```
Call to a member function first() on null
```

So if everyone could help me to understand ? 
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys i have merged your answers and it works, here is the result :

```
    $levy = $this->createMock(Levy::class);
    $userOwnLevy = $this->createMock(User::class);
    $contract = $this->createMock(Contract::class);
    $userHasContractCollection = $this->createMock(ArrayCollection::class);
    $firstUserHasContract = $this->createMock(UserHasContract::class);

    $firstUserHasContract->method('getUser')->willReturn($userOwnLevy);
    $userHasContractCollection->method('first')->willReturn($firstUserHasContract);
    $contract->method('getUserHasContract')->willReturn($userHasContractCollection);
    $levy->method('getContract')->willReturn($contract);
```

Comment: could you mark your own answer as accepted? this way it'll be easier to find for the next persons who will have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Let's declare our mock by chronological order

```
$userOwnLevy = $this->createMock(User::class);
$contract = $this->createMock(Contract::class);
$userHasContractCollection = $this->getMockBuilder(ArrayCollection::class);
$firstUserHasContract = $this->createMock(UserHasContract::class);
$userHasContract = $this->getMockBuilder(UserHasContract::class);
```

Then declare the methods by the opposite order of `$levy->getContract()->getUserHasContract()->first()->getUser();`

```
$firstUserHasContract->method('getUser')->willReturn($userHasContract);
$userHasContractCollection->method('first')->willReturn($firstUserHasContract);
$contract->method('getUserHasContract')->willReturn($userHasContractCollection);
$userOwnLevy->method('getContract')->willReturn($contract);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change `willReturnMap` to `willReturn`:

```
$contract->method('getUserHasContract')->willReturn([$firstUserHasContract]);
```